# alert by passing string to alert function

Tags: javascript, alert

I want to show alert by passing string to alert function.When i put number its working fine.Please me.
If there is another good practice please inform me thanks.

My code- here $item['name'] is string-and this code in a foreach loop

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function remind(msg) { 
    var msg = "Time up!!!This is a reminder for <?php echo $item['name'];?>"+msg;
    alert(msg); 
    }
    </script>
    <input type=radio name=rm<?php echo $item['id'];?>1  class="r" value=5000 OnClick="mytime=setTimeout('remind('<?php echo $item['name'];?>')',1000)">1 min  //remind('<?php echo $item['id'];') working fine
    <input type=radio name=rm<?php echo $item['id'];?>2 class="r" value=5000 OnClick="mytime=setTimeout('remind()',3000)">5 min
    <input type=radio name=rm<?php echo $item['id'];?>3 class="r" value=5000 OnClick="mytime=setTimeout('remind()',600)">10 min
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What `<?php echo $item['name'];?>` is doing in `string` ?

Comment: $item['name']; returns a string

Comment: As you get the value of `$item` in a loop.. How could you access it in function ?

Comment: @Rayon:That i don't know but it working fine when i use 'remind('<?php echo $item['id'];?>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because when it is a string it looks like a variable reference. You need to wrap strings in quotes.

```
"mytime=setTimeout('remind(\'<?php echo $item['name'];?>\')',1000)"
```

Comment: how to wrap it inside a onclick function